Weighted sums of partial Bell polynomials
Define $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1})$ and $B_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$ to be the partial and complete exponential Bell polynomials, respectively. I'm using the same conventions as wikipedia, if there's any confusion.
I'm working on a problem where I've found that it would be nice to compute the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1})$. Of course, I can just compute this directly and it's not a problem, but I was wondering if there were any way to simplify the expression.
Using a generating function argument (just by taking a derivative and then coefficient matching), I've found that you can write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}B_{n-k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k}) x_k
$$
(note the right hand side is in terms of the complete Bell polynomials).
This formula is tantalizingly close to the recursion for the complete Bell polynomials,
$$
B_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} B_{n-k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k})x_k
$$
and I've spent a few days playing around with it on and off to try to get it to be something nicer. I'm definitely not the best at manipulating these kinds of expressions, so I'm wondering if anyone has any insight (or if, indeed, there already is a simple closed form known for the original sum I wanted to compute). Thanks!

Faa Di Bruno's formula states that
$$
D^n f(g(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(g(x)) B_{n,k}(g'(x), \ldots, g^{(n-k+1)}(x)),
$$
where $D$ is the derivative. Setting
$$
g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n!} z^n,
$$
we can set $x=0$ in the above equationto find that $D^n f(g(x)) |_{x=0}$ is what you are looking if $f^{(k)}(0) = k$. Using Taylor's formula, we can infer the expression of $f$:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n = x e^x.
$$
Therefore we have the equality
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k B_{n,k}(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-k+1}) = D^n g(x) e^{g(x)} |_{x=0}.
$$
Reexpanding the right hand side with Leibniz' formula yields the identity you found. However, finding a nicer expression for it is equivalent to finding a nicer expression for $D^n g(x) e^{g(x)} |_{x=0}$ which, I'm sure you understand, surely does not exists.

This is great! I actually figured this out on my own right before you posted this, so I'm going to mark this as accepted because I think this form is actually useful for my purposes. Thanks!
